# Persist the dynamically added tags after refreshing JSP

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

My application is in Spring and using .jsp for view. I have created some tags dynamically using jquery. Now if i refresh the page my all the dynamically created tags removed from page but I want to persist the dynamically added tags after refreshing.

Comment: You'll have to re-add the tags when the page reloads, or else send some information back to the server via ajax to tell it what to do the next time the JSP code produces the page.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways for this. One way could be like this:

1. Whenever you dynamically create your tags using jquery, you also save them on server using ajax. jquery makes ajax interactions really convenient.
2. When you load the page on browser, make sure that you are fetching your dynamically created tags from the database and displaying them on your JSP.

This way your tags won't be lost if you reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the values from the database as an object and use tags from [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) to display them in the JSP page. This way they will be displayed after refreshing too.

Hope you find this answer useful though its a late reply.